# Does ASP.net Identity 2.0 allow the same user to login simultaneously from two different browsers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

We are moving our application to use ASP.net Identity 2.0, one of the feature we are looking for is to allow the same user to login simultaneously from two different browsers, is this possible in ASP.net Identity 2.0...

Comment: The standard workings like that. Did you experience any problems in your implementation?

Comment: Yes it does. In fact, doing the opposite (restricting user from logging simultaneously) is a hard work and usually not worth of an effort.

Answer (score 0):

The standard workings like that. Did you experience any problems in your implementation?